# How do I test Network Manager PKCS11 usage?

Tags: networkmanager, wpa-supplicant, tpm, 802.1x

I am trying to access a wifi network which is 802.1x protected with a certificate and the private key is stored in a TPM2.

When I try to connect to the network using Network Manager, I get the error message

```
Sep 19 11:23:40 mylaptop wpa_supplicant[1419]: ENGINE: cannot load private key with id 'pkcs11:model=SLB9670%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00;manufacturer=Infineon;serial=0000000000000000;token=mytoken_tpm2_pkcs11;id=%37%37%38%39%30%30%63%35%66%33%39%61%61%62%33%31;type=private;pin-value=userpin' [error:42000065:pkcs11 engine::object not found]
```

I read this error message as Network Manager, or actually wpa_supplicant, is unable to retrieve the private key.

I am fairly certain the data is there:

```
# pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/libtpm2_pkcs11.so -L
Available slots:
Slot 0 (0x1): mytoken_tpm2_pkcs11
  token label        : mytoken_tpm2_pkcs11
  token manufacturer : Infineon
  token model        : SLB9670
  token flags        : login required, rng, token initialized, PIN initialized
  hardware version   : 1.38
  firmware version   : 7.85
  serial num         : 0000000000000000
  pin min/max        : 0/128
Slot 1 (0x2): 
  token state:   uninitialized


# pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/libtpm2_pkcs11.so -O
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x1)
Public Key Object; RSA 2048 bits
  label:      
  ID:         37373839303063356633396161623331
  Usage:      encrypt, verify
  Access:     local
```

I would like to validate the configuration string used in Network Manager. How can I test Network Manager's token access? How can I make sure `'pkcs11:model=SLB9670%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00;manufacturer=Infineon;serial=0000000000000000;token=mytoken_tpm2_pkcs11;id=%37%37%38%39%30%30%63%35%66%33%39%61%61%62%33%31;type=private;pin-value=userpin'` is a correct setting?